# condition with first zero and 'n' from each customer id then get the letter name and add to next column pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input:

```
 wdf = pd.DataFrame([[101,'y', 1, 'reg'],
                    [101,'y', 1, '1098'],
                    [101, 'y',0, 'Reg'],
                    [101, 'y',0, 'sed'],
                    [101,'n',0,'VA'],
                    [102, 'y',1, 'Paymode'],
                    [102, 'y',0, 'roy'],
                    [102, 'n',0, 'Reg'],
                    [103, 'y',1, 'reg'],
                    [103, 'n',0, 'PCA'],
                    [103, 'n',0, 'FXD']
                  ]
                  , columns=['cus_ID', 'emailflg','Paperlessmode', 'types of paper'])
```

output:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[101,'y', 1, 'reg','VA'],
                    [101,'y', 1, '1098','VA'],
                    [101, 'y',0, 'Reg','VA'],
                    [101, 'y',0, 'sed','VA'],
                    [101,'n',0,'VA','VA'],
                    [102, 'y',1, 'Paymode','Reg'],
                    [102, 'y',0, 'roy','Reg'],
                    [102, 'n',0, 'Reg','Reg'],
                    [103, 'y',1, 'reg','PCA'],
                    [103, 'n',0, 'PCA','PCA'],
                    [103, 'n',0, 'FXD','PCA']
                  ]
                  , columns=['cus_ID','emailflg', 'Paperlessmode', 'types of paper','first occurance_paper_n_0'])
```

I want to identify the types of paper which is presence in first zero and 'n' in Paperlessmode for each customer id with Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset then groupby then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
wdf['first occurance_paper_n_0'] = wdf['cus_ID'].map(wdf[wdf['Paperlessmode'].eq(0)
                                                      & wdf['emailflg'].eq("n")]
                                   .groupby('cus_ID')['types of paper'].first())
```

---

```
print(wdf)
    cus_ID emailflg  Paperlessmode types of paper first occurance_paper_n_0
0      101        y              1            reg                        VA
1      101        y              1           1098                        VA
2      101        y              0            Reg                        VA
3      101        y              0            sed                        VA
4      101        n              0             VA                        VA
5      102        y              1        Paymode                       Reg
6      102        y              0            roy                       Reg
7      102        n              0            Reg                       Reg
8      103        y              1            reg                       PCA
9      103        n              0            PCA                       PCA
10     103        n              0            FXD                       PCA
```

Or using `drop_duplicates` and `map`:

```
cond = wdf['Paperlessmode'].eq(0)& wdf['emailflg'].eq("n")

wdf['first occurance_paper_n_0'] = wdf['cus_ID'].map(dict(
  wdf.loc[cond,['cus_ID','types of paper']].drop_duplicates('cus_ID').to_numpy()))
```